# Using a file-static function as a callback from a different translation unit

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

**a.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

static int a = 41;

static void test(void){
    a++;
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
}

int main(void){
    set_callback(test);
    call();

    return 0;
}
```

**b.c**

```
static void (*callback)(void);

void set_callback(void (*func)(void)){
    callback = func;
}

void call(void){
    if (callback){
        callback();
    }
}
```

**b.h**

```
void set_callback(void (*func)(void));
void call(void);
```

This compiles without warnings with `-Wall` and prints out `a: 42` as expected.

Now, this might not be the best practice, since the writer of `a.c` probably doesn't expect `test()` to be called from another file and the variable `a` modified, but is this legal C code? Will it work portably on different platforms and compilers?

Comment: Functions are always static. You might confuse it with the `static` storage class specifier which determines the linkage for functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine code and even good code. There is no need for your `test` callback to be global.

The compiler is responsible to ensure that the function isn't called outside the translation unit, before doing any optimizations that would affect calling it from outside.

If it sees that a pointer to the function is passed to an external function, it has to refrain from doing incompatible optimizations to the function.

Thus, the only effect is that the object file won't export a `test` symbol (This is termed [Internal Linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I would usually mark such functions as static, but was wondering because I have seen static functions (i.e. functions with internal linkage) described as being inaccessible from other translation units. I guess "inaccessible" just means not visible (i.e. the symbol isn't exported and can't be directly referred to in another translation unit), though. It does make sense that the compiler would refrain from doing incompatible optimizations when it sees that a pointer to the function is passed to an outside function.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> Now, this might not be the best practice, since the writer of a.c probably doesn't expect test() to be called from another file and the variable a modified, but is this legal C code?

If the writer did not want his `test()` function to be called from another file, he should not have passed a pointer to it to an outside module!

When the writer called  `set_callback(test);` he knew he was passing his static method to an outside module, and giving that outside module permission to call it.

The point is that the author is in charge of the `test` method and where it goes.  He's not prevented from doing anything, but he can control where his data goes; and he ***chose*** to pass it to an outsider.